# Prove that $q_{ki} = \lambda_1[1+ \mathcal{O}((\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2})^k)] \; \text{for all } i \; \text{with} \; (x_1)_i \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let A be a real symmetric $n x n$ matrix having the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ with $$|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2| \geq ... \geq |\lambda_n|$$
and the corresponding eigenvectors $x_1...x_n$ with $x_1^Tx_k = \delta_{ik}$. Starting with an initial vector $y_0$ for which  $x_1^Tx_k \neq 0$, suppose one computes $$y_{k+1}=\frac{Ay_k}{||Ay_k||} \; \text{for} \; k=0,1,2,...$$
with an arbitrary vector norm $||\cdot||$, and concurrently the quantities $$q_{ki} = \frac{(Ay_k)_i}{(y_k)_i}, \; 1 \leq i \leq n, \; \text{in case} (y_k)_i \neq0$$
and the Rayleigh quotient: $$r_k = \frac{y_k^TAy_k}{y_k^Ty_k}$$

Prove that
$q_{ki} = \lambda_1[1+ \mathcal{O}((\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2})^k)] \; \text{for all} i \; \text{with} \; (x_1)_i \neq 0$ and $r_k = \lambda_1[1 + \mathcal{O((\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2})^{2k})}]$

How can I prove the cost of operator for the Rayleigh quotient and the quatities, I know the relation $Ax_j = \lambda_jx_j \; \text{for} \ j=1,2...,n$. Do we have to use the 2-norm, and the condition number in order to prove both quotient and the quantities ?

Comment: @ Alexander , it is amazing that you have not corrected the error that I reported on your statement. Indeed $(\dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2})^k$ tends to $\infty$ with $k$ and your required estimates practically are non-sense. Then I think that you did not understand one word of my answer below; now, I'll no more waste my time answering your questions.

Comment: Dear sir, the reason I did not correct your suggestion about $r_k$ is because that formula I got in the book "Introduction to Numerical Analysis by Stoer," more specifically it's problem 14 in chapter 6. On the other hand, I think the only mistake, that I have been making is $x_1^Tx_k = \delta_{ik}$ should be $x_i^Tx_k = \delta_{ik}$. Below is how I did that problem

Comment: @loupblac Thank you for your answer. Below is actually the solution of this homework from my professor. And, if you still think that my formula for $r_k$ is wrong. Please contact the author of that book, because I have no authorization to fix him.

Comment: @ Alexander , sometimes mathematics are not good for the health.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_0=\sum_i a_ix_i$. Note that $y_k=z_k/||z_k||$ where $z_k=A^ky_0=\sum_ia_i{\lambda_i}^kx_i$. Remark that $|\lambda_2|=\cdots=|\lambda_p|>|\lambda_{p+1}|$. Then $z_k={\lambda_1}^k(u+v_k)$ where $u,v_k$ are orthogonal non-zero vectors s.t. $u$ and $x_1$ are parallel and $||v_k||=O((\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k)$. Thus $Az_k={\lambda_1}^k(\lambda_1u+w_k)$ where $u,w_k$ are orthogonal vectors s.t. $||w_k||=O((\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k)$.

Note that $r_k=\dfrac{{z_k}^TAz_k}{{z_k}^Tz_k}=\dfrac{\lambda_1||u||^2+O((\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{2k})}{||u||^2+||v_k||^2}$ (according to Cauchy-Schwarz). Clearly $r_k=\lambda_1+O((\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{2k})$.

Conclusion: Your formula for $r_k$ is obviously false ! (change the fraction into its inverse)

EDIT. Your post is so badly written ! In particular, I do not understand a word about the last three lines. Finally, I think that $q_{k,i}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of $q_k$ in some basis ; then the required result is true (if, in the result, the fraction is modified) ; indeed, $q_{k,i}=\dfrac{\lambda_1 u_i+w_{k,i}}{u_i+v_{k,i}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$y_{k+1} = \frac{Ay_k}{||Ay_k||} $$ is unit vector propotional to $Ay_k$, then we can write that formula in the form 
$$y_{k+1} = \frac{A^{k+1}y_0}{||A^{k+1}y_0||}$$
let $$y_0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}B_ix_i, \; \text{where } B_1 = x_1^Ty \neq 0$$
Then 
$$A^ky_0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} B_i\lambda_i^kx_i$$
$$ = B_1 \lambda_1^k x_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} B_i\lambda_i^kx_i$$
$$ = \lambda_1^k(B_1x_1 + \mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^k))$$

a) For $q_{ki}$
$$q_{ki} = \frac{e_i^T(Ay_k)}{e_i^Ty_k}$$
$$ = \frac{B_1\lambda_1^{k+1}e_i^Tx_i+ \mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^k)}{B_1\lambda_1^{k}e_i^Tx_i+ \mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^k)}$$
$$ = \lambda_1+\mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^{k}) $$
as $k \to \infty$ if $e_i^Tx_i \neq 0$

b) For $r_k$

Some $x_1^Tx_i = 0$ for $i \neq 1$
$$y_K^TAy_k = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_i\lambda_kx_i)A((\sum_{j=1}^{n} B_j\lambda_kx_j))$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}B_i^2\lambda_i^{2k+1}$$
and $$y_K^Ty_K = \sum_{i=1}^{n}B_i^2\lambda_i^{2k} $$

since $|\lambda_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\lambda_n|$
then, $r_k$ will be 
$$\frac{y_K^TAy_K}{y_K^Ty_K} =  \frac{1 +\mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^{2k+1}) }{1 + \mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^{2k})}$$
$$ = \lambda_1 +\mathcal O(\left|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right|^{2k}) $$